# Classic ASP: Creating safe array (as generated by Request.ReadBinary) from normal array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, binary

I've run into some difficult-to-refactor classic ASP code. It's saving data from Request.Form into the database. It's doing so by using:

```
Dim RequestData
RequestData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
```

Before this happens, I'd like to remove a particular field from Request.Form, however the documentation on BinaryRead indicates that if you touch Request.Form before or after BinaryRead, you'll get an error.

I could potentially change this on the pages requesting this functionality, but that would be extremely complicated.

So, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Dim tempData
tempData = Request

tempData.Form("BadField") = ""

requestBytes = ConvertToSafeArray(tempData) 'I'm not aware of anything that actually does this
```

So, any thoughts?

Comment: Why "extremely complicated"? Most upload scripts are generating key/value collections, you can simply remove an item from that collection by its key, which is the form element name

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm) or [ASP Uploader](http://aspuploader.com/). Since ASP can't handle files in a normal upload, these libraries parse form fields and files out of the binary request data into an internal data structure.

You could modify them to ignore or erase special fields.